# Как заставить ansible перелогиниться при включенном pipelining?

Tags: ssh, ansible

Когда в конфиге `ansible` включен `pipelinining`, он переиспользует ssh-соединение для всех задач.
Иногда одна из задач меняет привилегии текущего пользователя, например, добавляет пользователя в группу, и для применения этих привилегий приходится перезапускать весь playbook.

Конкретно, я столкнулся с этой проблемой при установке `docker`, для избежания `become: true` задач контейнеризации, я добавляю текущего пользователя в группу `docker`.

Существует ли способ форсировать реаутентификацию без перезапуска playbook?

*Я знаю, что можно переопределить переменную окружения `ANSIBLE_SSH_PIPELINING=0` для всего playbook, но он довольно большой - повторный запуск гораздо быстрее.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если говорить о конкретной проблеме добавления пользователя в группу, то перезагрузить группы можно без выхода:

```
sudo gpasswd -a username somegroup
newgrp somegroup
```

Или конкретно для вашего случая:

```
newgrp docker
```

В случае Ansible этот трюк может не сработать, в таком случае, начиная с версии 2.3, можно указать Ansible [повторно установить соединение](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html):

```
- user: name={{ansible_user}} groups=docker append=yes
- name: update effective groups to include docker
  meta: reset_connection
```

Comment: Вот оно! Мета. То, что надо, благодарю.